# Moving Columns/Text in VIM

Tags: string, vim, text

I was wondering how I might go about moving around Columns/Text around in VIM using a string. I have a short list of names I have to reorder, which need to be placed in Last Name First Middle to First Middle Last.

So here would be an example list:

- Plant, Robert A.
- Page, Jimmy
- Bonhham, John H.
- Jones, John Paul

I was thinking that the string should look something like this:

```
:s/\([A-z]\{2}\)\(\[A-z]\{2}\)/2\1/
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you double those backslashes to get them to display here?  Use 4 spaces of indentation to format a code block, and you won't need to double-escape. Assuming that was what happened, I removed the double backslashes

Comment: Yes, I didn't get a chance to adjust it so to save time I used a double slash to help display it on stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I recommend [using the `\v` "very magic" flag](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) to avoid all the other internal escaping of metacharacters.  This will work with a replacement like:

```
 :s/\v([A-z]+),\s+([A-z]+)(\s+[A-z.]+)?/\2\3 \1
```

Breaking it down:

- `([A-z]+)` Capture the last name into `\1`
- `,\s+` A literal comma and one or more spaces
- `([A-z]+)` Capture the first name into `\2`
- `(\s+[A-z.]+)?` Capture the middle name *with* its leading spaces, since it may not exist. Also permit the `.`, and end with a `?` to make the whole construct optional, into `\3`
- `\2\3 \1` Replace with the second group (first name) followed immediately by the middle name `\3` with *no space in between* because the space was captured along with the middle name. Then append `\1` the last name.

If the names could be possibly more than `[A-z]+`, you may alternatively use `[\S]+` to capture all non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Hey Michael. I tested it on in a ksh unix shell for the regex file that I needed to use. For one I can tell it works great so I appreciate the help. Didn't realize \v would work here. Using "\s" seems to make a better grouping.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
:%s/\([[:alpha:]]\+\), \([[:alpha:]]\+\)\( [[:alpha:]]\+\.\?\)\?/\2\3 \1/g
```

This captures last, middle (optional), and first, and reorders them in the replacement. You'll probably need to include additional characters in the `[[:alpha:]]` collection, but this works for your example.

For more information, learn how the excellent and comprehensive `:help` is structured; all the information is in there (you just need to know how to find it)! There are also many very similar regular expression questions here on Stack Overflow.